# Setting spellcheck attribute to false does not remove red underlines

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to toggle between `<textarea spellcheck='true'>` and `<textarea spellcheck='false'>`.

**Chrome**: once `spellcheck=true` is set, it cannot be "unset", that is, even if you set false, the red underlines do not dissapear (at least on macOS).

**Firefox**: behaves as expected

**Safari**: I still don't understand what it is doing, only when I click around I get the red underlines, and then it does not disappear.

I'm suspecting this is OS specific. Reports form other OSs are appreciated.

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

textarea.focus();

form.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

 const trueOrFalse = e.target.value;
 textarea.focus();
 textarea.setAttribute("spellcheck", trueOrFalse);
 output.textContent = textarea.parentNode.innerHTML;

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/140% monospace;
  background: #eee;
  color: #777;
  padding: 60px;
}

textarea {
 margin: 32px 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 120px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

label {
 color: #777;
 cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="spellcheck" />
    <span>spellcheck true</span>
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" value="false" name="spellcheck" checked />
   <span>spellcheck false</span>
  </label>
</form>
<div>
  <textarea spellcheck="false">Here is an example of a misspeltz word</textarea>
</div>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the implementation (in Chrome, at least) is that the `spellcheck` mode only works on newly inserted text. In order to completely "reset" the field, you need to remove and reinsert the `textarea`.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

textarea.focus();

form.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

 const trueOrFalse = e.target.value;
 const text = textarea.value;
 textarea.parentNode.removeChild(textarea);
 textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
 textarea.textContent = text;
 document.querySelector(".textarea-container").appendChild(textarea);
 
 textarea.focus();
 textarea.setAttribute("spellcheck", trueOrFalse);
 output.textContent = textarea.parentNode.innerHTML;

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 16px/140% monospace;
  background: #eee;
  color: #777;
  padding: 60px;
}

textarea {
 margin: 32px 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 120px;
 font-size: 16px;
}

label {
 color: #777;
 cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="spellcheck" />
    <span>spellcheck true</span>
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" value="false" name="spellcheck" checked />
   <span>spellcheck false</span>
  </label>
</form>
<div class="textarea-container">
  <textarea spellcheck="false">Here is an example of a misspeltz word</textarea>
</div>

<div id="output">
</div>
```